# Image Submit Button Not Working Properly

Tags: form-submit, onsubmit

I am trying to use an image to submit a form on my page. Here is the code I currently have, that works:

```
  <form name="regForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"  id="regForm" >
   ....input form here....
      <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Register">
  </form>
```

What I am attempting to use, that does not work:

```
  <form name="doRegister" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="doRegister">
   ....input form here....
  <input type="image"  value="Register" src="../register.png"  style="vertical-align: middle; height: 30px; width: 66px;" onsubmit="submit-form();" />
```

When clicking the button to submit, it reloads the page, without actually submitting the data.

Is this a Post v Get issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this trouble in the past when doing something like this, try `<input type="image" src="../register.png" alt="Register" name="doRegister" />`
and in php use `$_POST['x_doRegister']` (the `x_` might not be needed)

Comment: I have this in my code if($_POST['doRegister'] == 'Register') { ect...}

Comment: try `if( isset( $_POST['x_doRegister'] ) ) { etc...}` instead